# npm unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled - issue

Tags: node.js, npm

gettting the following error, when running npm install create-react-app

Windows 10
node v18.13.0
npm  v8.19.3

error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: write EPROTO B8360300:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922

any help or work around greatly appreciated. Tried multiple online solutions nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 7):

I found a 'fix'. It works with node v18.16.0.

<s>Note that this disables SSL validation completely so use with caution.</s>

> Edit: I don't know to what degree this does or doesn't cause security risks. Needless to say, use at your own risk, do not use this production, ymmv, water is wet, etc. :)

First, go the URL with the cert you're having issues with. Click on the lock icon in the address bar and view the site's cert info. The exact steps vary by browser, but look for a way to export the site's cert chain as a pem file. Make sure you get the whole certificate chain, not just the cert for the site. Copy that file to your local machine and note the path.

Next, create an environment variable pointing to the pem file.

`export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/file.pem`

Finally, create a file called `openssl.cnf` and paste the following in it. In my case I put this file at the root of my project.

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

<strike>I'm not sure if this next step is necessary because I found it in a python thread, but I also set an env var for the conf file created above. I'd really appreciate it if someone would note in the comments if this step is necessary or not. I was too lazy to test it at the time.</strike>

Thanks to the folks in the comments who answered that!

Next, create an env var that points to the openssl.cnf:

`export OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/openssl.cnf`

Comment: Thanks ! This was working fine for me also. But I'm pretty sure that It didn't disable SSL validation completely.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. Why do you put "export" before the variable name? I believe I just need the key and the value in my environment variables. Is that a Linux thing?

Comment: Yeah, its a linux/mac thing.

Comment: @LaneGoolsby - Yes, setting the env var for the conf file is necessary. (And a big THANKS for solving my issue!)

Comment: In a Windows cmd it is necessary and it is `set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\path\to\openssl.conf` and it does the trick!

Answer (score 3):

In Node v17 and higher, OpenSSL has been updated to v3.0.7. `SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT` is the option that went from enabled by default in OpenSSL 1.1.1 to disabled by default in OpenSSL 3.0:

> Secure renegotiation is now required by default for TLS connections
>
> Support for RFC 5746 secure renegotiation is now required by default for SSL or TLS connections to succeed. Applications that require the ability to connect to legacy peers will need to explicitly set SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT. Accordingly, SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT is no longer set as part of SSL_OP_ALL.

Source: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/migration_guide.html

Read more about the underlying issue in [my answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76012131/5550386).

A (temporary) solution would be to downgrade to Node v16. Another solution is to re-enable secure renegotiation (`UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation`):

```
OPENSSL_CONF=<(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf ; echo Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation) node my-file.js
```

**Previous suggestion (will not solve your issue):**

Other things you could try:

- if you are in a company with its own CA, set the company cert in the environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`

  - Windows: `set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\some-folder\your-cert.pem`
  - Linux: `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/ssl/certs/your-cert.pem`
- if you are in a company where you got your own NPM registry, e.g. nexus or Artifactory, set this in the config file for NPM or Yarn (if you already have a `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`, you may have to delete that to be able to use the specified registry):

  - `.npmrc`:

    ```
    registry = "https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-official/"
    ```
  - `.yarnrc.yml` (Yarn modern):

    ```yaml
    npmRegistryServer: "https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-official/"
    ```
  - `.yarnrc` (Yarn classic):

    ```
    registry "https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-official/"
    ```
- Instead of deleting your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` to use your company registry, you could also try replacing the default registry with your company registry in the file:

  ```bash
  $ sed -i 's|registry.yarnpkg.com|artifactory.acme.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-official|g' yarn.lock
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It's Probably because you're using a vpn, or your using a Corporation computer, try to disable the vpn or reach for your Corporation to help you more.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't just tell my IT department to disable the VPN - they mandate that all corporate computers are on it at all times.

Comment: My company requires VPN for some actions (e.g. fetching source code), but not others (e.g. building code locally with NPM). I disabled VPN before running my npm commands, and the error went away.

Comment: This was the issue for me.  Disabling my VPN fixed it right away.