# Npm ERR! request to [url] failed, reason: SSL routines:final_renegotiate unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs3

I recently updated the version of Node JS for a Vue 3 application.
To migrate from Node V.16 to Node V.18.
However, after successfully updating via the *.exe installer.
I am unable to perform the "npm install" or "npm login" command.
Here is the full error when I try to login to our corporate 'custom' repository:

command executed: npm login
result :

```
npm ERR! request to https://....../login failed, reason: write EPROTO 98310000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled :c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:
npm ERR!
```

I have of course found different POSTs talking about the same problem. Here are the actions
Please note that

everything worked fine with Node V.16.20.2

I tried without success:

- Create a custom openssl.cnf with "Options =
  UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation" and insert the file path in the
  environment variable [**OPENSSL_CONF**]
- downgrade the cryptography package in python => **pip install
  cryptography==36.0.2**
- Create and set the following environment variable =>
  **NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0**
- Set the registry correctly in the .npmrc file. With authentication token

Here are the NPM and Node versions on my post.

- **Node: v18.17.1**
- **Npm: 10.0.0**

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason.

There is an SSL renegotiation issue between the Node/NPM client, OPENSSL and the load balancer when the request tries to reach the Artifact server on Azure Devops. The request did not reach the Artifactory and ended at the proxy/'load balancer' level
If you are using a firewall/VPN, allowing renegotiation would be helpful (for example: allowing renegotiation at the Netscaler endpoint or your Load Balancer's SSL negotiation configuration would help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

same issue to publish into my nexus.
cause : [npm unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled - issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147968/npm-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled-issue)

no solution found except downgrade npm...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).