# Encounter "SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled" while getting token

Tags: teams-toolkit

I created a basic bot project(typescript) using the Teams Toolkit. When running it on my local machine, an error occurs when executing the section in ouath2client.js where axios is used to get a token. The error is:

'write EPROTO C0050000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:\n'

Is there any way to temporarily disable SSL/TLS renegotiation when running locally?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue you're facing is more likely related to node rather than the Teams Toolkit. You might want to check if the solution provided in this answer ([npm unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled - issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147968/npm-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled-issue)) can help resolve your problem.