Node.js Error: EPROTO - SSL Unsafe Legacy Renegotiation Disabled
I am encountering this error in my Node.js project and do not know how to fix it.
I have updated Node and OpenSSL to the latest versions.
This is my error:
Error: write EPROTO 4C190000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:95:16)
I have updated Node and OpenSSL to the latest versions and it still doesn't work.

This error is because you are using recent OpenSSL specifically 3.0 up; it now defaults to rejecting defective ancient servers that don't support RFC5746. The correct solution is to fix or replace the server, but if you can't (and people who post on Stack generally have no power or status) use the solution in the effective dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147968/npm-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled-issue .
